# Question on positive square root of an operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Let $T$ is a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert Space $H$. Let there exists a unique positive square root of $T^{*}T$. Let us call it as $P$

Then how can I show that the dimension of the range of $T$ is the same as that of the range of $P$?

For this, I am trying to show that their null spaces are equal.

I started with $x \in KerT$ $\rightarrow$ $Tx=0$ $\rightarrow$ $\langle Tx,Tx\rangle=0$ $\rightarrow$ $\langle T^{*}Tx,x\rangle=0$

From here, I can't imply that $Px=0$.

Help, please

Comment: I think the dimension of the range is  $T$ is the dimension of the range of $P^{2}$.

Comment: I think the same but I have been given to show it for T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $\ P\ $ is a square root of $\ T^*T\ $, then $\ T^*T=P^2\ $.

Comment: That will imply that $P^{2}x = 0$ and not Px=0? Isn't it?

Comment: $\ \langle T^*Tx,x\rangle= \langle P^2x,x\rangle= \langle Px,Px\rangle\ $

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method of proof.  By the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition)
one  may write
$
  T=UP,
  $
where $U$ is a partial isometry which also satisfies,
$
  U^*T=P.
  $

This implies that $U$ is an isometric isomorphism from  $\text{Ran}(P)$ to $\text{Ran}(T)$  and, in particular,
$$\text{dim}(\text{Ran}(P)) = \text{dim}(\text{Ran}(T)).$$

---

**PS**:  Thanks to user "lonza leggiera"
for pointing out my initial misunderstanding of the method based on the fact that $\text{Ker}(T)=\text{Ker}(P)$.   This
implies that
$$
  \text{Ran}(T)\simeq
  H/\text{Ker}(T) =
  H/\text{Ker}(P) \simeq
  \text{Ran}(P),
  $$
thus solving the problem.

However this method only proves that the ranges are algebraically isomorphic and cannot decide, for instance, whether or
not  one
range  is closed in case the other one is known to be closed.

Comment: I would presume the OP is relying on the isomorphism theorem $\ \text{Ran}(T)\cong H/\text{ker}(T)\ $, which doesn't require $\ H\ $ to be finite dimensional.

Comment: Absolutely.  I'll try to correct it soon.